# Android Linear Layout DoubleLine

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to have a textfield beside a button and for it to fill the max amount of width space no matter what screen size. The issue is when I try different screen sizes the amount of extra space between them increases. I tried this:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnQuestion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/Question" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center" >

    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

  </LinearLayout>
```

But this happens: http://snag.gy/VOAuA.jpg

This is what I had orignally:

http://snag.gy/pzlmP.jpg

But is is in relative layout and when resized the space increases. 
I presume this is because it is set to wrap content?
Anyway if you can help me solve this I would be thankful!

Comment: Are you intentionally put the marginTop?

Comment: `fill the max amount of width space no matter what screen size`. Looks like match_parent ?

Comment: (your linearlayout is horizontal...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have layout_marginTop for the EditText, but not the Button. The top of the EditText will therefore be 44dp offset from the top of its container (the LinearLayout)